# UTF-32 Decode using python is having issues

Tags: python, udp

I have a UDP python server on port `80`, i want some one to hit the server and also send an encoded message "Start Server" using `UTF-32` but when i try to decode it, it gives

```
request_code = bytes.decode(x, 'utf-32')
TypeError: descriptor 'decode' requires a 'bytes' object but received a 'tuple'
```

Here is the code:

```
Constants.Server0 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
Constants.Server0.bind((local_ip, udp_port_main))
Constants.Main_server_data = Constants.Server0.recvfrom(2048)
for x in Constants.Main_server_data:
    request_code = bytes.decode(x, 'utf-32')
if request_code == 'Start Server':
    print("Authorized!")
```

I need help regarding this and can get me through it.

Comment: variable ```x``` has value of tuple data type, it is giving error. check at which index your required value and provide that value for decode function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[recvfrom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom):

> ... The return value is a pair `(string, address)` where string is a string representing the data received and address is the address of the socket sending the data.

So try:

```
request_code = bytes.decode(x[0], 'utf-32')
```

or a better style:

```
for string, address in Constants.Main_server_data:
    request_code = bytes.decode(string, 'utf-32')
```